# how to use group by clause with 'case' in the below select query

Tags: sql, oracle

here I need to do group by clause dynamically, howto implement case switch here

```
 SELECT
    COUNT(*) noofrecords,
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) order_by,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date), 'MM'), 'month') value
FROM
    tab_name
WHERE
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2019
    AND CASE 'MONTH'  ----- getting this value from a variable
        WHEN 'MONTH'   THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)
    END = 2            ----- setting this value from a variable
GROUP BY
    CASE 'YEAR'    ----- getting this value from a variable 
        WHEN 'YEAR'   THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)
    END
ORDER BY
    order_by
    enter code here
```

Comment: Apart from grouping "switch" query  working as excepted

Comment: What issue you are facing with the mentioned query?

Comment: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
-----------------------------------------------------------------
in groupby clause, I need to implement more than one case but it was throughs error.

Comment: You will need to use such dynamic code in select clause also as in group by clause you can not select columns directly except your grouped columns or you will need to use some sort of aggregation function in select clause

Comment: Thanks,when I try to use dynamic code in the select clause, then it was working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all the expressions in the `SELECT` clause to either be aggregation functions or in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_cursor      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  p_start_units VARCHAR2(10) := 'YEAR';
  p_year        NUMBER       := 2019;
  p_month       NUMBER       := 2;

  p_out_month   VARCHAR2(10);
  p_out_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  OPEN p_cursor FOR
  SELECT COUNT(*) noofrecords,
         TO_CHAR(
           CASE p_start_units
           WHEN 'YEAR' THEN TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' )
           END,
           'month'
         ) AS value
  FROM   tab_name
  WHERE  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = p_year
  AND    CASE 'MONTH'
         WHEN 'MONTH' THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)
         END = p_month
  GROUP BY
         CASE p_start_units
         WHEN 'YEAR' THEN TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' )
         END
  ORDER BY
         CASE p_start_units
         WHEN 'YEAR' THEN TRUNC( start_date, 'MM' )
         END;

  LOOP
    FETCH p_cursor INTO p_out_count, p_out_month;
    EXIT WHEN p_cursor%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_out_month || ': ' || p_out_count );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Test Data**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tab_name ( start_date ) AS
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-03-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> february : 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25654463bf52d49d63e004ae894e3a5f)*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a subquery to define the columns based on the variables and then aggregate and order using them.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as noofrecords, order_by, value
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date), 'MM'), 'month') as value
             EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date) as order_by
             (CASE 'YEAR'    ----- getting this value from a variable 
                   WHEN 'YEAR' THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)
              END) as grouping_var
    END
             (CASE 'MONTH'  ----- getting this value from a variable
                  WHEN 'MONTH' THEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM start_date)
              END) as filter_criteria
      FROM tab_name
      WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM start_date) = 2019
     ) t
WHERE filter_column = 2  ----- setting this value from a
GROUP BY grouping_var, order_by, value
ORDER BY order_by;
```

The query doesn't exactly make sense.  But I suspect that when you apply to your actually problem, you'll see how this approach helps.